# How to Convert bmp file to pcx file

Tags: c#, bmp, pcx

Any method or dll found to convert the image format bpm to pcx?

I have been trying to following code.

```
 public static void ConvertBMP2PCX(string bmpFilePath)
    {
        List<byte> listBytePCX = new List<byte>();

        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(bmpFilePath);
        int bmpWidth = bmp.Width;
        int bmpHeight = bmp.Height;

        byte[] byteBmp;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
            byteBmp = ms.ToArray();
            ms.Close();
        }

        int bytesPerLine = (bmpWidth + 7) / 8;
        int xEnd = bmpWidth - 1;
        int yEnd = bmpHeight - 1;

        byte[] header ={
        0x0A,           // "PCX File"
        0x05,           // "Version 5"
        0x01,           // RLE Encoding
        0x01,           // 1 bit per pixel
        0x00, 0x00,     // XStart at 0
        0x00, 0x00,     // YStart at 0
        (byte)(xEnd&0xFF), (byte)((xEnd>>8) & 0xFF),      // Xend
        (byte)(yEnd&0xFF), (byte)((yEnd>>8) & 0xFF),      // Yend
        (byte)(xEnd&0xFF), (byte)((xEnd>>8) & 0xFF),      // Xend
        (byte)(yEnd&0xFF), (byte)((yEnd>>8) & 0xFF),      // Yend
        0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0E, 0x0E, 0x0E, 0x0D, 0x0D, 0x0D, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x0C,   //48-byte EGA palette info
        0x0B, 0x0B, 0x0B, 0x0A, 0x0A, 0x0A, 0x09, 0x09, 0x09, 0x08, 0x08, 0x08,  
        0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x06, 0x06, 0x06, 0x05, 0x05, 0x05, 0x04, 0x04, 0x04,  
        0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  
        0x00,          // Reserved byte, always x00
        0x01,          // 1 bit plane
        (byte)(bytesPerLine&0xFF), (byte)((bytesPerLine>>8) & 0xFF),      // Bytes per scan line: (XEnd - XStart,  1) / 8
        0x01, 0x00,    // Palette type: 1 means color or monochrome
        0x00, 0x00,    // Horizontal screen size (not used)
        0x00, 0x00     // Vertical screen size (not used)
     };
        listBytePCX.AddRange(header); // Write most of header data
        listBytePCX.AddRange(new byte[54]);// pad the 128-byte header


        byte[] rowIn = new byte[bmpWidth * 3];
        int[] bits = { 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1 };

        byte[] bytes = new byte[2];
        int last = 0;
        int count = 0;
        for (int y = 0; y < bmpHeight; y++)
        {
            //getPixelRow(rowIn, y);
            int currentByteCount = (y + 1) * bytesPerLine;
            if (currentByteCount > byteBmp.Length)
            {
                currentByteCount = byteBmp.Length;
                rowIn = new byte[bmpWidth * 3];
            }

            for (int i = y * bytesPerLine; i < currentByteCount; i++)
            {
                rowIn[count] = byteBmp[i];
            }
            count = 0;

            for (int x = 0; x < bmpWidth; x += 8)
            {
                int n = x + 8;
                if (n > bmpWidth) n = bmpWidth;
                int b = 0;
                for (int j = x; j < n; j++)
                    if (rowIn[j + j + j] != 0)
                        b |= bits[j - x];
                if (last == b && count < 63)
                    count++;
                else
                {
                    if (count > 0)
                    {
                        bytes[0] = (byte)(count | 0xC0);
                        bytes[1] = (byte)last;
                        listBytePCX.Add(bytes[0]);
                        listBytePCX.Add(bytes[1]);
                    }
                    last = b;
                    count = 1;
                }
            }
            if (count > 0)
            {
                bytes[0] = (byte)(count | 0xC0);
                bytes[1] = (byte)last;
                listBytePCX.Add(bytes[0]);
                listBytePCX.Add(bytes[1]);
                count = 0;
                last = 0;
            }
        }

        //Save pcx file
        string pcxFilePath = bmpFilePath.Substring(0, bmpFilePath.LastIndexOf('.') + 1) + "1";
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(pcxFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            fs.Write(listBytePCX.ToArray(), 0, listBytePCX.Count);
            fs.Flush();
            fs.Close();
        }
    }
```

But it doesn't work,only create a thin line with pcx format.

Comment: Not sure why a question with full code was ever closed, but the issue in the code is that saving an image as bmp format is not at all the same as extracting the actual data bytes from it. You can do that with `LockBits` and `Marshal.Copy` though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a port of the [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) library for .NET at http://magick.codeplex.com/. The library supports both the BMP and the PCX format and also converting images from one format to another.

Comment: The library works eazy and fine. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad I could help. Feel free to "accept" the answer :) ...

Comment: @AndyFong please can you provide me the code to convert the bmp file to pcx file.. i am developing an windows app using C#.. any ideas!! thanks in advance

Comment: You can follow the link http://magick.codeplex.com/ provided above, turned the tab DOCUMENTATION. There are some sample codes.